# Falta de tradução para “Este é um comentário de "agradecimento".”

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, regressao

O comentário que aparece por baixo desta opção regrediu, i.e, está em inglês novamente.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido. No próximo build as alterações vão pro ar